# Django Signals - creating folder on model create

Tags: python, django

I got a model where I would like to create a folder when a model is created:
The model:

```py
class Drive(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=150, editable=False,
                            default='C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/RavNet/media/storage/drives/{}'.format(str(id)))

    def save(self):
        super().save()
```

I am trying to use signals, but I must admit this is my first ever attempt at making a signal not following a tutorial on point, and even after reading the documentation I am having a tough time.

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Drive
import os

@receiver(post_save, sender=Drive)
def create_drive(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        os.mkdir(Drive.path)
```

Nothing happens when I create a new drive model via the django admin. I have tested out my code in the shell and using a placeholder path (C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/RavNet/media/storage/drives/test) that I know works in the signal in a try to debug, and have gotten as far as realising I am having two issues.

The first: When calling the Drive.path in the shell, I am getting the path:

```
'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/RavNet/media/storage/drives/<django.db.models.fields.UUIDField>'
```

Instead of a path with the actual id as I hoped for. How do I solve this?

Secondly, my signal isn't working. It's like it isn't getting called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must import your signals in `app.py`. Please check your `app.py`. It must be like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = '...'

    def ready(self):
        import your_project.your_app.signals
```

Also your `app/__init__.py` must include this code:

```
default_app_config = 'your_project.your_app.apps.YourAppConfig'
```

Comment: I did this, but it my signal is still not being run when a new drive is created

Comment: How do you create Driver object? Could you share your create code?You overrided save() method, perhaps sender object can change with this method but I am not sure.

Comment: hmm I solved it by actually just adding the creation of the folder to the save method, when creating the Drive object. However I am still facing the issue of Drive.path returning ```'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/RavNet/media/storage/drives/<django.db.models.fields.UUIDField>'```
instead of ```'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Python/RavNet/media/storage/drives/123...Some...id'```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have many signals and don't want the app.py defined in your app.
you could do so:

- signals are in folder `app/signals/__init__.py signal1.py signal2.py`
- import all files in `__init__.py`

```
from .signal1 import * 
from .signal2 import *
```

- `from app.signals import *` inside of `app/views/__init__.py`